# can't expand link as my cutomization in snippets.json

Tags: vim, emmet

I expect to epxpand link into

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="" />
```

and  expect to epxpand link:css into

```
<link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all" />.
```

Here is my way to customize it.

```
vim  .vim/snippets.json
"link": "<link type=\"text/css\"  rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"\" />",
"link:css": "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"${1:style}.css\" />"
```

and edit .vimrc

```
let g:emmet_html5 = 0
let g:user_emmet_settings = webapi#json#decode(join(readfile(expand('~/.vim/snippets.json')), "\n"))
```

I found that in my vim-emmet:
link was expanded as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
```

link:css was expanded as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
```

Why link was not expanded as

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="" />
```

and link:css was not expanded as

```
<link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.